# Is there a way to automatically snap loose points of lines to close by vertices with Quantum GIS?

Tags: qgis, editing, snapping, digitizing, line

I have a vector layer of lines that were drawn with the snapping option off. I need to have them snapped but, there are hundreds of lines. Is there any solution to do this automatically or semi-automatically?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Maybe the answers to this question are helpful: [How to simplify a routable network?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/12370/how-to-simplify-a-routable-network)

I [used GRASS v.clean](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/12370/how-to-simplify-a-routable-network/12380#12380) in the end.